# PhpStorm show error warning on save like Sublime Text

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, phpstorm

Sublime Text 2 all but eliminated my syntax errors by a displaying error warning upon save.

How can I get the same feature in PhpStorm. I am using version 10.

Again, I would like a dialog box to pop up upon save in PhpStorm if there is a syntax error.

PhpStorm has a squiggly line which I brightened up as much as possible, I just move around far to quick to catch these errors, which is typically a missing semicolon, where the error mark is tiny.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such built-in functionality.

Comment: Are there any Plugins?

Comment: I do not know about that unfortunately. You will have to check it yourself (plugins screen has search field .. so you should be able to narrow that list quite a bit). But considering how saving (autosaving in particular) works in general I would not count on this.